# Not able to access other drives except the c drive

Tags: 14.04

my PC is dual booted, so whenever i change it to Ubuntu and try to access other drives it shows it is temporarily not accessible. but we can access only c drive. is there any way we can access the other drives also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window may not be getting totally shutdown, if you want to access other drives, try restarting the system and then switch to ubuntu. Restarting totally shutdown the windows